# html5 validation on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML5 form validation will not cover the situation where, starting from a group of checkboxes, at least one of them is checked. If a checkbox has the required attribute it must be checked, this is what I can get at most.
So I built a workaround that works fine (code in the snippet). The issue is that this works for one group of checkboxes. But I want my code to be valid even if I add more chackboxes groups. I need a suggestion on how to make it valid for multiple groups.
Any idea?

```js
function bindItemsInput() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[name="option[]"]')
    var radioForCheckboxes = document.getElementById('radio-for-checkboxes')
    function checkCheckboxes () {
        var isAtLeastOneServiceSelected = false;
        for(var i = inputs.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (inputs[i].checked) isAtLeastOneCheckboxSelected = true;
        }
        radioForCheckboxes.checked = isAtLeastOneCheckboxSelected
    }
    for(var i = inputs.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('change', checkCheckboxes)
    }
}
bindItemsInput() // call in window onload
```

```css
.checkboxs-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.checkboxs-wrapper input[name="radio-for-required-checkboxes"] {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="checkboxs-wrapper">
    <input id="radio-for-checkboxes" type="radio" name="radio-for-required-checkboxes" required/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option3"/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

A second snippet with the relevant HTML (*not working, goal of the question is to fix this*). **It will have now the same ID for the radio button: that is invalid and is the reason of the question**:

```js
function bindItemsInput() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[name="option[]"]')
    var radioForCheckboxes = document.getElementById('radio-for-checkboxes')
    function checkCheckboxes () {
        var isAtLeastOneServiceSelected = false;
        for(var i = inputs.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (inputs[i].checked) isAtLeastOneCheckboxSelected = true;
        }
        radioForCheckboxes.checked = isAtLeastOneCheckboxSelected
    }
    for(var i = inputs.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('change', checkCheckboxes)
    }
}
bindItemsInput() // call in window onload
```

```css
.checkboxs-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.checkboxs-wrapper input[name="radio-for-required-checkboxes"] {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="checkboxs-wrapper">
    <input id="radio-for-checkboxes" type="radio" name="radio-for-required-checkboxes" required/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option3"/>
  </div>
  <div class="checkboxs-wrapper">
    <input id="radio-for-checkboxes" type="radio" name="radio-for-required-checkboxes" required/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="option1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="option2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="option3"/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

The form will be valid if at least on products[] checkbox and one option[] checkbox is checked. So I need the javascript to run indipendently for option[] and for products[]. If I have selected one item in groups[] but none in products[] then only products will be surrounded by the box and marked for completition

Comment: what do you mean by group?  name = option[], name = option[1] ... ?

Comment: as you see in my snippent group is when the checkboxes share the same name. So at least one of the options should be checked. So another group will have a different name: i.e. products[]

Comment: sorry i dont understant show an example with more groups... and display the result wanted..

Comment: you dont precise what is a group...i doubt only the name is changing, for me you create anew complete form?

Comment: @MisterJojo my code on that side is fine. The radio button is checked if one or more checkboxes is checked. So I won't post the form without at least the value of one checkbox.

Comment: @MisterJojo yes editing my question

Comment: you have the same id.... for radio-for-checkboxes so you cant use in your function..the id must be unique..

Comment: and that is my question ;-). I mentioned it also: _It will have now the same ID for the radio button: that is invalid and is the reason of the question:_

Comment: @Frenchy btw you forgot to note that the radios have also the same name but also this is invalid in this situation, since the two are indipendent ;-)

Comment: @LelioFaieta The question is tagged as jQuery. Why are you not using it in your code?

Comment: I used only vanilla js but jquery can be used if needed. The issue wouldn't change using jQuery

Comment: if all the checkboxes are not checked also the radio is not. in my real code I call `bindItemsInput() ` on change of any checkbox to redo the check. In this fiddle this is not reproduced since it is not part of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this what I imagine you are looking for:

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

myForm.addEventListener('change', bindItemsInput)  // global change event listener 

function bindItemsInput(e) // 
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('div.checkboxs-wrapper input[type=checkbox]'))  return  
    // to reject unconcerned checkbox 

  let groupDiv   = e.target.closest('div.checkboxs-wrapper')
    , radioGroup = groupDiv.querySelector('input[type=radio]')
    , checkGroup = groupDiv.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')
    ;
  radioGroup.checked = [...checkGroup].reduce((flag,chkBx)=>flag || chkBx.checked, false)
  }


// ------ verification part-------------------
myForm.onsubmit=e=> // to verify
  {
  e.preventDefault() // disable submit for testing
  console.clear()

  // chexboxes checked values:
  let options  = [...myForm['option[]'] ].reduce((r,s)=>{ if (s.checked) r.push(s.value);return r},[])
    , products = [...myForm['product[]'] ].reduce((r,s)=>{ if (s.checked) r.push(s.value);return r},[])

  console.log('options = ', JSON.stringify( options ))
  console.log('products = ', JSON.stringify( products ))

  myForm.reset()   // clear anything for new testing
  console.log(' form reseted')
  }
```

```html
  <form name="my-form">

    <div class="checkboxs-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="rGroup_1" required >
      <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option3">
    </div>

    <div class="checkboxs-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="rGroup_2" required> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="product1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="product2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="product3">
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was trying to implement. This is applicable no matter what and how many checkboxes groups I have. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

if i understant. so you have to give another id and another name of course, try this:

```
function bindItemsInput() {
    var inputs = $("input[type=checkbox]");
    var radios = $("input[type=radio]");
    function checkCheckboxes () {
        var isAtLeastOneServiceSelected = false;
        for(var i = inputs.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (inputs[i].checked) isAtLeastOneCheckboxSelected = true;
        }
        radios.each( function(){
            $(this).checked = $(this).siblings($("input[type=checkbox]:checked")).length > 0;
        });
    }
    for(var i = inputs.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('change', checkCheckboxes)
    }
}
```

Comment: your code will outline both the checkboxes groups (products[] and option[]) in the situation where products[] have one checked and option[] none. My goal is to have only option[] outlined in that case

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery this can be done with a lot less code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkCheckboxesInSameGroup = function() {
    var inputs = $(this).children("input[name='option[]']");
    var radio = $(this).children("input[name^='radio-for-group']")[0];
    radio.checked = inputs.is(":checked");
  };
  $(".checkboxs-wrapper").on('change', checkCheckboxesInSameGroup);
});
```

```css
.checkboxs-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="checkboxs-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-for-group1" required/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option3"/>
  </div>
  <div class="checkboxs-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-for-group2" required/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="option3"/>
  </div>   
</form>
```